# How do I setup an ASP.Net/IIS dev enviroment on a Mac for my Flash developer?

Tags: asp.net, flash, macos, development-environment

No, no, I'm not getting hives ;).

I am able to run a local version of my .NET 3.5 site on IIS and troubleshoot whilst I develop. However, my flash developer is forced to log onto our Windows 2003 and mess with our staging server when he wants to see how his work is doing. This is unacceptable, I understand, but right now there are time concerns so this  hack is going to have to fly for a little.

How do I set up a dev environment for my flash developer to be able to work on his local machine? I'm sure this gets done in other places.

Comment: Hi, what kind of a development environment are you wanting him to have on his Mac?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question title to actually be a question, or better description of the problem?

Comment: still have no idea what the problem is...

Answer (score 6):

VMWare Fusion or Parallels, or give him a virtual machine/PC that he can Remote Desktop to from his Mac.

Comment: this is what I am trying to get around, is there no way to get around this?

Comment: Get around any of those options? No.. if you want him to have IIS to test on, then he needs a Windows install of some sort. If he is just testing Flash that can sit anywhere (and doesn't rely on the .net side) then he could use Apache on his Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Not to sound the fool, but isn't Flash not platform dependent? Is the flash developer doing anything more complex than connecting to a remote client to update an .swf file? You don't "need" to be running windows/iis to copy a file from mac to windows. You might try the Remote Desktop client:

http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx

or set up an FTP account (on the staging server in question?) for him. I agree with the above about using Parallels or VMWare. It's not necessarily a "hack" or "workaround" that you can use and test on multiple platforms. It's a huge plus! As a user of VMWare and ex-parallels user, I recommend VMWare. It takes about as long as "installing windows" to be up and running on a mac, and the resources from your Mac can be available via a "documents" on the desktop (or other) if you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of Mac is it? The Intel ones can run Windows natively.

Answer (score 1):

Dual boot Windows on his Mac with [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/macosx/features/bootcamp.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Setup IIS in a VMWare Fusion virtual machine. Do a simplified install of Windows XP and it should run excellent.

That way you can interface with the IIS Server from Mac OS X or from other PC's from anywhere on the local network for that matter.

I use Vmware Fusion to run subversion and Apache servers and it runs beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

well an alternative is the [Q Emulator](http://www.kju-app.org/)

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual problem? As I see it, Flash dev. makes a Flash movie, and tests it locally, if it needs to communicate with the server, it does just that. If the Flash dev. wants to see it in a page, or see how it communicates with the surrounding HTML and Javascript, he uploads the file to the server using a ordinary windows share (aka Samba-share) or FTP or whathaveyou and then presto, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered http://www.virtualbox.org">VirtualBox which is a free alternative to Parallels and Bootcamp. I'm running Windows XP pro on my MacBook no problem at all - note it's for Intel Macs only though.